# What account do workflows run as?

Tags: 2010, workflow

I need to move a file from SharePoint to a network share (on a linux machine).  Since impersonation has issues (Double hop?) I need to just give permission to the account that the service is running as.

The workflow will be designed as a state machine WF.

Is there a way to see / change which account this is?

Thanks

Comment: The workflow runs within the SharePoint Timer Service (SPtimerV4, Owsstimer.exe).

Answer (score 1):

The workflow runs within the SharePoint Timer Service (SPtimerV4, Owsstimer.exe)